# How to convert simple rectangle bounding box to a polygon on the spheroid

Tags: postgis

Using PostGIS, I need to find certain data within a bounding box. The data is stored as point data in a column. The bounding box is basically the visible area of a map, as a user sees it:
[image: bounding box as the maps user sees it]

However, as the map is more zoomed out using ST_MakeEnvelope from the coordinates given by the map results in a polygon that misses most of the area the user is looking at:
[image: bounding box on the spheroid]

Using PostGIS functions, how can I construct the bounding box from the map coordinates in such a way as to search the area the user sees on the map?

Comment: You are obviously suffering from some sort of coordinate system confusion, but it is hard to tell from the question exactly what it is. Could you give a concrete example of one of these bounding boxes, what coordinate system it is in, what coordinate system you *want* it to be in, and roughly what part of the Earth you expect it to cover?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is of course handling the difference between the map view frame and a polygon with the corners of the map view frame projected onto a spheroid. I just wasn't sure what the right answer is.

It turns out that to select the expected results (what the user expects to see) I simply needed to make sure both sides of the query in PostGIS explicitly were cast to `::geometry` instead of `::geography`.